# Function for smart polling

Tags: javascript, polling

Hello I want to make a smart polling function in which after every 4 empty responses the interval should be doubled. But if the interval reaches the maximum interval it should stay on that value only. What function should be written for it.

This is code of getting response from a php code.

```
function updateChat() {
    console.log("inside updatechat");

    setInterval(function()

        $.ajax({
            //type: "POST",
            url: "file.php",
            //data: id,
            //dataType: JSON,

            success: function(response) {
                var result = JSON.parse(response);
                //console.log("Result is " +result);

                for (var i in result) {

                    $(".message_box").append('<p class = "shout_msg">' + result[i] + '</p>');
                    $(".message_box").scrollTop($(".message_box")[0].scrollHeight);
                }

            }


        }), interval);

}
```

What would be my polling function?

Comment: It is not php, it is JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` calls the callback every constant time interval... what you need is `setTimeout`:

```
var INITIAL_INTERVAL = 500; // 0.5 sec
var MAX_INTERVAL = 120000; // two minutes
var interval = INITIAL_INTERVAL;

var pollingFunction = function() {
    $.ajax({
        //type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        //data: id,
        //dataType: JSON,

        success: function(response) {
            var result = JSON.parse(response);
            if (result.length == 0) { // or whatever condition to check return of empty result
                 // empty result - poll server at slower pace
                 interval *= 2;
                 if (interval > MAX_INTERVAL) {
                     interval = MAX_INTERVAL;
                 }
            }
            else { 
                 // reset interval to initial quick value
                 interval = INITIAL_INTERVAL;
            }
            //console.log("Result is " +result);

            for (var i in result) {

                $(".message_box").append('<p class = "shout_msg">' + result[i] + '</p>');
                $(".message_box").scrollTop($(".message_box")[0].scrollHeight);
            }

            // activate the pollingFunction again after 'interval' ms
            // important - set the timeout again of the polling function
            setTimeout(pollingFunction, interval);
        }


    })
 }

 // activate the polling function the first time after interval ms
 // important - set the timeout once (or call the polling function once) from outer scope.
 setTimeout(pollingFunction, interval);
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it worked for me. I have a doubt can you explain how that both the setTimeout function works

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about both setTimeout - I'll try to revise the answer with added explanation. If the answer works for you you can mark it as a solution (check mark below the vote buttons) so this question will be marked as 'solved'.